# TOP 10 article visitor counting via PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wanted to know if it is possible to obtain the 10 most viewed articles that week (**Between today and 7 days back**) using PDO PHP.

The main problem is that on two separate tables. Primary table is the table of articles. And the second table is a table visitors by IP.

**Posts (ARTICLE TABLE):**

> 1.ID (text)
>
> 2.TITLE (text)
>
> 3.TEXT (text)

**Visitor (COUNTER TABLE):**

> 1.ID (number)
>
> 2.IP (text)
>
> 3.DATE (TIMESTAMP)
>
> 4.ID_POSTS (text)

**The full php code:**

```
$week_start = date('Y-m-d',time()+( 1 - date('w'))*24*3600);  
$week_end =  date('Y-m-d',time()+( 7 - date('w'))*24*3600); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM visitor WHERE DATE BETWEEN '".$week_start."' AND '".$week_end."'  LIMIT 0, 10 ";
$result = $db->prepare($query); 
$result->execute(); 
$i=1;

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$post[$i]=$row[ID];
$i++;
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE ID_POST = '".$post[$i]."' LIMIT 0, 10";
$result = $db->prepare($query); 
$result->execute(); 

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo<<<PRINT
$row[ID].$row[TITLE]: $row[text]
PRINT;
}
}
```

The problem I think is that you have to count how many people were at the table wrote the secondary then move the primary table.

**Steps:**
1. Count how many entered each article each week by the secondary table
2. extract the 10 Most Viewed same week
3. present the 10 most read article in the same week by the main table

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrong sequence in query . Limit must be comes after WHERE clause!!

Comment: USe your query as `SELECT * FROM POSTS  WHERE ID_POST = '".$post[$i]."' LIMIT 0, 10"`

Comment: @Saty ITS NOT THE PROBLEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a query, I would expect a `COUNT()`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT 10`.  Hence:

```
SELECT id_post, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM visitor v
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '".$week_start."' AND '".$week_end."'
GROUP BY id_post
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 0, 10 ;
```

Note:  The `WHERE` clause always followed the `FROM` clause.

Also, you should not be embedding dates in the query string.  You should learn to use parameters instead.

Comment: Its not working... can you post the full code pls @gordon TIA

Comment: Maybe `COUNT(DISTINCT ip)` is closer to what the OP wanted

Comment: @TheQuestionerMan . . . You should explain what "not working" means.

Comment: 1. Is visitor and not visitor v 2. I change the date format. Thank you @gordon

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select id, count(1) as cnt
from visitor where date > (NOW()- INTERVAL 7 DAY) group by id) v1, posts p
where v1.id = p.id
order by v1.cnt desc
limit 10
```

Not tested.